# load cross domain xml by Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-domain

Hi
Is it possible to load an XML file from a domain that differs from scripts domain with pure javascript and without using a php/asp/jsp/... script as proxy?
Something like xmlHttpRequest but with ability to manage cross domain requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called JSONP. I know the name sucks, because it's not really related to JSON. But this requires you have control over the other domain. You need to wrap your XML inside a function call, or assign it to a javascript variable:

`func('<xml></xml>');`

or

`var myxml = '<xml></xml>';`

So if your other domain returns one of these two formats, you can use the `<script src="http://otherdomain/yourjsonp"></script>` syntax in your html to load that data in JavaScript. It's a little hacky but a lot of people use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but it doesn't help me. actually I need to load other sites RSS and traverse it with pure JS. So I just can read files that are provided by others and that file is XML.

Comment: Sorry then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with yql! (Yahoo did it for you)

Go to [this site](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FYahoo%27%20and%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2Ftable%2F*%5Bcontains(.%2C%22Founder%22)%5D%2F%2Fa%27&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+xml+where+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fnews.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Ftopstories') and simple at the "select from url='xxx' " replace the xxx with your xml url. Use the url created at the text box below and do a simple xmlrequest. You won't have any cross-domain prolems