# XMLHttpRequest error in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am trying to make an example in JavaScript using the `XMLHttpRequest` object. I made an html file as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
     AJAX simple example
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContent">
          <h1>This is an AJAX example</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

and my script is like this:

```
//simple AJAX example:
var myRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
   myRequest = new ActuveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
myRequst.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(myRequest.readyState);
    if(myRequest.readyState === 4){
       var p = document.createElement("p");
       var text = document.createTextNode(myRequest.responseText);
       p.appendChild(text);
       document.getElementById("mainContent").appendChild(p);
    }
};

myRequest.open("GET", "source.txt", true);
myRequest.send(null);
```

I keep getting an error when opening the html file in chrome, I get the following error in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:.../ajaxRequestExample/source.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: run it from `http://` instead of `file:///`. there are chrome flags you can use as well, but for more realistic testing, a simple HTTP is highly recommended. if you have python, there's a built-in one that you can startup with one command line.

Comment: You should use some server to be able to get any content from there via `ajax`. It's a good practice even if you do some experiments.

Comment: i guess that @dandavis try to suggest that you run your files from a **localhost**.. plus, use **micro ajax** instead https://code.google.com/p/microajax/

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem, but unless you're supporting Internet Explorer < 7, you don't need the `ActiveXObject` branch...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: actually you need activex for loading `file://` assets in IE7.still probably pointless...

Comment: Still wouldn't work with `ActuveXObject` ;-P

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: it should work as-shown, depending on the zone, but let's keep it real: who cares? EDIT: actually no it won't work as-shown, the ie branch needs to come first becasue IE7 has a "Broken" xmlHttpReuest on `file:///`s

Answer (score 0):

Chrome thinks that you request a resource from a different domain than the one which served itself. Your code doesn't look wrong, but it seems that you are not running a server on the backend. 
Your ajax should talk to a server which will 'serve' your 'source.txt'.

So, maybe you can try running a server that listens to http://localhost

and try your script again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [cross-domain-policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain-policy) problem and not a chrome only problem. But when it comes to load files from local mozilla firefox is the one you need with less restrictions. You can check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783792/load-cross-domain-xml-by-javascript/33811792#33811792) also if you want for further development to load files with http request from different domain name.